# XPath for specific tag

Tags: java, xpath

I am trying to get the value of the tag "fax" ( see sample XML below ) using XPath in java ...

I decided to try and get the nodes for "business" and step through the debugger to see if I could see the tags ...does not seem to work ...the code fragment I am using is:

```
String path = 
"/locationDetailResponse/locationInfo/locationBusinessList/business"

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Element userElement = (Element) xPath.evaluate(path, documentObject,
            XPathConstants.NODE);
```

documentObject contains an org.w3c.dom.Document object

```
<location>
   <locationInfo>
     <warehouseId>99</warehouseId>

   <nearByLocations>
    <location>
     <name>Morganton, NC</name>
     <url>morganton-nc-hvac</url>
   </location>

   <location>
    <name>Statesville, NC</name>
    <url>statesville-nc-plumbing</url>
   </location>
  </nearByLocations>

  <locationBusinessList>
   <business>
    <id>123</id>
    <fax>(800) 555-1212</fax>
   </business>

   <business>
     <id>456</id>
    <fax>(800) 666-2323</fax>
   </business>
 </locationBusinessList>

</locationInfo>
</location>
```

Any ideas on the proper XPath expression I should be using ?

Comment: I don't see a node with `locationDetailResponse` name..

Comment: Yes ...my "fat fingering" ...locationDetailResponse == location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try change `/` to `//` at beginning of line,

or use [local-name](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35413_01/doc.722/e35419/dev_xpath_functions.htm#autoId6):

```
//*[local-name()='location']/*[local-name()='locationInfo']/*[local-name()='locationBusinessList']/*[local-name()='business']
```